# How to split one column into two columns such that it should maintain the data according to other columns using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Here is the table]

I want the above table to look like below table:-

[image: The table that I need]

I tried the below code:-

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT * FROM
(SELECT P.FACTOR_VALUE1 AS AGE,P.FACTOR_VALUE2 AS AREA, 
P.WEIGHTING AS BUY_FACTOR,0 AS SELL_FACTOR, 
P.START_DATE , P.END_DATE, L.PRODUCT_ELEMENT_ID 
FROM  PRICE_FACTOR_LOGIC L, PRICE_FACTOR P
WHERE L.MAPPING_ID=P.ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID AND  L.PRODUCT_ELEMENT_ID =1
AND L.FACTOR_ID =0
AND L.PRICE='BUY'

UNION

SELECT P.FACTOR_VALUE1 AS AGE,P.FACTOR_VALUE2 AS AREA, 
0 AS BUY_FACTOR,P.WEIGHTING AS SELL_FACTOR,
P.START_DATE, P.END_DATE, L.PRODUCT_ELEMENT_ID 
FROM  PRICE_FACTOR_LOGIC L, PRICE_FACTOR P
WHERE  L.MAPPING_ID=P.ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID  AND L.PRODUCT_ELEMENT_ID =1
AND L.FACTOR_ID =0
AND L.PRICE='SELL'  
) ORDER BY AGE,AREA, START_DATE
);
```

Comment: [From the accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557) "*Code or **sample data** in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem*"

Comment: As I mentioned above the weighting column should split as sell_factor and buy_factor according to start_date and end_date

Comment: You should also explain the logic behind your desired output. Which column do you want to "split"? And based on which rules?

Comment: UNION ALL should be used here. no point wasting the db's time looking to dedupe this data

Comment: Please get into the habit of using ANSI join syntax, standardised in 1992

Comment: You show some data, a Select and an expected result without any further information?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OP's use of "split" is probably the wrong word to use here, given that he's wanting to pivot 2 rows of successive buy/sell pairings into a single row of buy and sell.. There's also some logic/interpolation to do with the dates, it seems (probably what he means when saying split - the date range for the first SELL splits the date range for the first BUY into ttwo ranges)

Comment: Seems like the start date equals 1 day after the previous end date of the same type (buy or sell). However, you got a sell-end on 02/02/18 and a successive sell-start on the same day. Is that an error in the data or how should this be managed?

Comment: Here the Weighting column needed to split and when it has  same start_date but different end_date then weighting gets expired with lowest end_date and the remaining data goes to next row with new start_date and highest  end_date.

Comment: I guess I expressed myself not very well. On date 02/02/18, what is the sell price? 14.79 or 24.75?

Comment: @robert kock 24.75

Comment: Sorry, I meant 02-JAN-2018. On that single day you have to different sell prices.

Comment: What's the criterion to select 24.75 instead of 14.79?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without any joins using `UNPIVOT` then finding the most recent values using the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function and the re-grouping around the date boundaries:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( age, start_date, end_date, price, weighting, product_element_id ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-11-11', DATE '2017-12-21', 'BUY',   0.76, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-11-11', DATE '2017-12-19', 'SELL', 16.27, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-12-20', DATE '2018-01-02', 'SELL', 14.79, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-12-22', DATE '2027-11-11', 'BUY',   0.71, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2018-01-18', DATE '2027-11-11', 'SELL', 24.75, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT age,
       product_element_id,
       MIN( DT ) AS start_date,
       MAX( DT ) AS end_date,
       MAX( start_buy_weighting  ) AS start_buy_weighting,
       MAX( start_sell_weighting ) AS start_sell_weighting
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         LAST_VALUE( CASE PRICE WHEN 'BUY' THEN weighting END )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY product_element_id ORDER BY dt ASC )
           AS start_buy_weighting,
         LAST_VALUE( CASE PRICE WHEN 'SELL' THEN weighting END )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY product_element_id ORDER BY dt ASC )
           AS start_sell_weighting,
         SUM( value ) OVER ( PARTITION BY product_element_id ORDER BY dt ASC )
           AS grp
  FROM   table_name
  UNPIVOT(
    dt FOR value IN ( start_date As 1, end_date AS 0 )
  ) p
)
GROUP BY age, product_element_id, grp
```

**Output**;

```
AGE PRODUCT_ELEMENT_ID START_DATE  END_DATE START_BUY_WEIGHTING START_SELL_WEIGHTING
--- ------------------ ---------- --------- ------------------- --------------------
  1                  1  11-NOV-17 19-DEC-17                 .76                16.27
  1                  1  20-DEC-17 21-DEC-17                 .76                14.79
  1                  1  22-DEC-17 02-JAN-18                 .71                14.79
  1                  1  18-JAN-18 11-NOV-27                 .71                24.75
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to join *sells* and *buys* using proper date criterias and then assign period dates using three functions: `least()`, `greatest()`, `lag()`. Query below gave me desired results, please test it and modify if needed:

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/1481)</sup>**

```
select greatest(d1, nvl(lag(d2) over (order by d1) + 1, d1)) start_date, 
       d2 end_date, price_buy, price_sell 
  from(select least(b.start_date, s.start_date) d1, least(b.end_date, s.end_date) d2,
              b.weighting price_buy, s.weighting price_sell, 
              b.start_date bsd, b.end_date bed, s.start_date ssd, s.end_date sed
         from (select * from t where price = 'BUY') b
         join (select * from t where price = 'SELL') s 
           on b.product_element_id = s.product_element_id 
          and s.end_date >= b.start_date and s.start_date <= b.end_date )
  order by start_date
```